# php get numbers based on array skip and start

Tags: php

so basically I'm looking for this logic:

3 skip 1 get 1 = 5 
5 skip 1 get 1 = 7
7 skip 1 get 2 = 9,10

is what I've got so far:

```
$start= 3;
$skip = 1;
$b= [1,1,2];            
$result = [];
foreach($b as $bsingle){                    
    $result []= $start += $skip+$bsingle;                   
}
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 10
)
```

I'm looking for this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 10
)
```

Comment: Well for starters you've only got three inputs, so will only get three outputs... Just add the remaining number to the `$b` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is actually this logic, which adds `$skip` to `$start`, then fetches as many values as are in the current value of `$b`:

```
$start = 3;
$skip = 1;
$b = [1,1,2];            
$result = [];
foreach($b as $bsingle) {    
    $start += $skip;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $bsingle; $i++) {
        $result[] = ++$start;    
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 10
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XdD9g)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative, using `array_reduce()` and `range()` to eliminate the loops:

```php
$start = 3;
$skip = 1;
$b = [1, 1, 2];

$result = array_reduce($b, function($acc, $get) use ($start, $skip) {
    $last_val = empty($acc) ? $start : end($acc); // Retrieves the last calculated value if available, otherwise begins with $start.
    $last_plus_skip = $last_val + $skip;

    $acc = array_merge($acc, range($last_plus_skip + 1, $last_plus_skip + $get));

    return $acc;
}, array());
```

Answer (score 1):

A super short, pure PHP 7.4 version (probably a bit harder to read and maintain than other solutions, this is mostly for funsies):

```
$result = array_reduce($b, fn($acc, $get) => 
   [...$acc, ...range(($start = end($acc) ?: $start) + $skip + 1, $start + $skip + $get)], 
   []);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/0lEM0**